# weighted linear regression and outliers

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model, weighted-regression

I am fitting a regression model with weights because without weights I have heterocedasticity. Suposse $\epsilon \sim N(0,x_i \sigma^2)$

Then check the weights through aux model

Model
$Y=X \beta + \epsilon$

Aux Model

$\frac{Y}{\sqrt{x_i}}=\frac{X}{\sqrt{x_i}} \beta + \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{x_i}}$

Aux model have homoscedastic stud. residuals. But when I delete the problematic outliers and repeat the fit of auxiliary model is not homocedastic. My question is the order,

1-fit without weight

2-delete problematic outliers

3-fit again with weight

4-check homocedastic residuals in aux model

or

1-fit with weight

2-check homocedastic residuals in aux model

3-delete problematic outliers

4-done

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Do you have an apriori reason for believing that the heteroskedasticity is proportional to $x$, or is that an empirical finding that, in principle, could have been driven by a few outliers?

Comment: Was an empirical finding, What should I do in that case? thanks!!!